# wxpython with matplotlib doesn't initialize

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I tried to use `matplotlib` in `wxpython`, but there is some problem.

```
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class MplCanvasFrame(wx.Frame):
    def _init_(self,parent):
        wx.Frame._init_(self, parent, size=(600, 400),
                        title='Matplotlib Figure with Navigation Toolbar')
        self.figure = Figure()

        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        x = np.arange(0, 6, .01)
        y = np.sin(x**2)*np.exp(-x)
        self.axes.plot(x, y)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
app = wx.App(redirect = False)
frame = MplCanvasFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It doesn't draw the curve at all.

but when I try this:

---

```
import wx
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, title = 'dasf',size = (600, 400))
figure = Figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(0, 6, .01)
y = np.sin(x**2)*np.exp(-x)
axes.plot(x, y)
canvas = FigureCanvas(frame, -1, figure)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The curve is drawed.

Why?

Comment: Try spelling `__init__` with two underscores on each side.

Comment: @acui145 Can you please answer your own question and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the spelling of `__init__`. there should be two underscores on each side (note that this is in two places in the code).